# perl, function only printing first element of the array

Tags: perl

I have an array that has several elements on it but when I pass the array as a parameter to a function and then call the function it only prints out the first element of the array multiple times. For example

```
my $element;
my $random_variable = "Testing";
my @the_array = ("hello", "bye", "hey");

foreach $element(@the_array)
{
  PrintFunction(@the_array, $random_variable)
}

sub PrintFunction{
 my ($the_array, $random_variable) = @_;
 // other code here

 print $the_array . "\n";

}
```

The result I get from this is

```
hello
hello
hello
```

The result I want is to print all the elements of the array as

```
hello
bye
hey
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
  PrintFunction(@the_array, $random_variable)
```

to:

```
  PrintFunction($element, $random_variable)
```

Your code passes the entire array to the sub, then you only print the 1st element of the array each time because you use the scalar variable `$the_array` inside the sub.  Since `foreach` grabs each element of the array, you probably meant to use `$element`.

Answer (score 1):

Add `Print @_;` to your sub to see what is passed to it. You will see:

```
hellobyeheyTesting
hellobyeheyTesting
hellobyeheyTesting
```

It means you are passing the entire array followed by the `$random_variable`. Therefore, `$the_array`in the `sub` will be always the first elements of `@the_array` which is hello. To fix that, you should pass each element of array iteratively by

```
foreach $element(@the_array)
{
  PrintFunction(@element, $random_variable)
}
```